# FIrebase react hooks only when a statement is true

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to make a Context API that supplies a connected user (not in Firebase Auth) and its respective DB entry in Firestore. I'm using Magic links as the auth method.

Here's my Provider:

```js
const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState<ethers.Signer | null>(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [userDoc, dbLoading] = useCollection(
    query(
      collection(firestore, "users"),
      where("walletAddress", "==", address ?? "") // issue is here <----
    )
  );
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dbLoading && userDoc?.empty) {
      addDoc(collection(firestore, "users"), {
        walletAddress: address,
      });
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [dbLoading]);

  const connect = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    provider
      .listAccounts()
      .then((accounts) => {
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
          const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);
          setSigner(signer);
          signer.getAddress().then((address) => {
            setAddress(address);
          });
          signer.getBalance().then((balance) => {
            setBalance(balance.toString());
          });
          setIsConnected(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const disconnect = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    magic.connect
      .disconnect()
      .then(() => {
        setAddress(null);
        setBalance(null);
        setIsConnected(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        userDoc: userDoc?.docs[0]?.data() ?? {},
        address,
        balance,
        isLoading: isLoading || dbLoading,
        isConnected,
        connect,
        disconnect,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

So the problem I'm having is quite straight forward: when the user is not logged in, it creates a new entry with 'walletAddress' of null. Before, I had the same Auth Provider as above, just stripped of all the Firestore logic. But after running into some issues when creating Route Guards, I decided to put it all into a single Provider. Is there a simple solution to this, or do I need to go back to two providers and work from there?